# UITableView reloadData crashes on reappearance in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, thread-safety, ios11

**Update**: In my view, the question is still relevant and so I am marking a potential design flaw that I had in my code. I was calling the asynchronous data population method in `viewWillAppear:` of VC1 which is **NEVER** a good place to populate data and to reload a table view unless everything is serialized in the main thread. There are always potential execution points in your code when you must reload you table view and `viewWillAppear` is **not** one of them. I was always reloading table view data source in VC1 `viewWillAppear` when returning from VC2. But an ideal design could have used an unwind segue from VC2 and repopulate the data source upon its preparation (`prepareForSegue`) right from VC2, only when it was actually required. Unfortunately, it seems like nobody had mentioned it so far :(

---

I think there are similar questions that have been asked previously. Unfortunately none of them essentially addressed the issue I'm facing.

My problem structure is very simple. I have two view controllers, say VC1 and VC2. In VC1 I show a list of some items in a UITableView, loaded from the database and in VC2 I show the details of the chosen item and let it be edited and saved. And when user returns to VC1 from VC2 I must repopulate the datasource and reload the table. Both VC1 and VC2 are embedded in a UINavigationController.

Sounds very trivial and indeed it is, till I do everything in the UI thread. The problem is loading the list in VC1 is somewhat time consuming. So I have to delegate the heavy-lifting of data loading task to some background worker thread and reload the table on main thread only when data load completes to give a smooth UI experience. So my initial construct was something similar to the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(self.application.commonWorkerQueue, ^{
        [self populateData]; //populate datasource
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData]; //reload table view
        });
    });
}
```

This was very much functional until iOS10 from when `UITableView` stopped immediate rendering through `reloadData` and started to treat `reloadData` just as a registration request to reload the `UITableView` in some subsequent iteration of the run-loop. So I found that my app started to occasionally crash if `[self.tableView reloadData]` hadn't completed before a subsequent call to `[self populateData]` and that was very obvious since `[self populateData]` isn't thread-safe anymore and if datasource changes before the completion of `reloadData` it is very likely to crash the app. So I tried adding a semaphore to make `[self populateData]` thread-safe and I found that it was working great. My subsequent construct was something similar to the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(self.application.commonWorkerQueue, ^{
        [self populateData]; //populate datasource
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData]; //reload table view
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.datasourceSyncSemaphore); //let the app know that it is free to repopulate datasource again
            });
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.datasourceSyncSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); //wait on a semaphore so that datasource repopulation is blocked until tableView reloading completes
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, this construct also broke since iOS11 **when I scroll down through `UITableView`** in VC1, select an item that brings up VC2 and then come back to VC1. It again calls `viewWillAppear:` of VC1 that in turn tries to repopulate the datasource through `[self populateData]`. But the crashed stack-trace shows that the UITableView had already started to recreate its cells from scratch and calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method for some reason, even before `viewWillAppear:`, where my datasource is being repopulated in background and it is in some inconsistent state. Eventually the application crashes. **And most surprisingly this is happening only when I had selected a bottom row that was not on screen, initially**. Following is the stack-trace during the crash:

[image: crashed stack trace]

I know everything would run fine if I call both the methods from the main thread, like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self populateData]; //populate datasource
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //reload table view
}
```

But that is not something that is expected for a good user experience.
I feel the issue happens since `UITableView` is trying to fetch the offscreen top rows on reappearance, when scrolled down. But unfortunately after understanding so many damn things I could hardly sort it out.

I would really like the experts of this site to help me out of the situation or show me some way around. Thanks a loads in advance!

PS: `self.application.commonWorkerQueue` is serial dispatch queue running in the background in this context.

Comment: A semaphore probably isn’t the best solution. Can you show the code for `populateData`?  It should not “touch” the table view array until all of the data is loaded and then it should update the property and call `reloadData`

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree that semaphore is not a good solution though I hardly found an alternative. And my `populateData` is pretty simple and it merely reads a lot of data from a SQLite database using fmdb and loads it to a `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` that acts as the datasource for binding. Thats all! Please let me know if you still need some code. I'll be happy to add. Thanks.

Comment: It is important that that function does not modify the data source array item by item; you need to load the items into a temporary array and then assign that array to your data source array in one step; that is why I asked you to show the populate function.

Comment: @Paulw11 That is a very good suggestion! I'll surely try that and apparently it should work. However, I was wondering if this is the best way to manage thread-safety with a temporary buffer or there exist some more elegant ways.

Comment: The best way to manage concurrent access is to avoid it whenever possible.  In this case concurrent access isn't necessary; Simply switch the arrays and reload the table when the new data is available

Comment: Got your point. Just wondering why UIKit is getting so much involved with rendering when its real power used to lie in its inherent dumbness and expecting for developer code for nearly every single move it made :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have definitely seen similar questions here before (involving earlier iOS versions) where updating the "live" array caused problems.

Comment: Now famous ppl out here have started down-voting the question who don't even have an answer of it. They don't even care for stating a reason for down-voting and click the button just because they can click it. Seems like stupidity at its best.

Comment: If you perform the switch between your temporary and “live” arrays on the main queue then the tableview cannot be in mid update since UI operations always occur on the main queue. If you are using the main queue to perform the array switch, it can’t be updating the table view

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I perfectly understand that your solution will give me a future-proof workaround and frankly it had already worked for me. Nevertheless, I am kinda chasing some wild geese! Think of a situation where in main queue 1. the tableview registers a reload call 2. datasources switch 3. tableview performs actual binding. The state after the final call is a tableview, bound to a datasource not originally asked for. Certainly there would be a subsequent `reloadData` call that'll put it in a consistent state. But what I'm really curious about is a way out for that momentary shortfall.

Comment: But that can't happen if you do everything on the main queue; iOS multitasking is non-preemptive and the main queue is a serial dispatch queue.

Comment: How do you know that since iOS 10 `reloadData()` is treated as a refresh request? Apple docs doesn't say a word about that. Is there any source?

Comment: I don't think it will fix your race, but if you want reloadData to actually reload the data, then call [self.tableView layoutSubviews] or layoutIfNeeded immediately after the reloadData call.

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski I know it had never been documented. But I had personally faced it (like many others, I guess) and had found that `reloadData` had stopped calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` immediately for rendering and had postponed it until next layout pass. To ensure put two breakpoints at `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You'll find from your stack-trace that the first one just gets called after your code executes `reloadData` while the second one gets invoked without any visible user code and possibly in the next run loop.

Comment: @RichWaters Yes I know `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` call is now postponed until next layout pass. So calling `layoutIfNeeded` immediately should get it done. But what I'm really worried here is about system invoked layout calls that in turn calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` when getting back to VC A and  that I don't have any control over. I was just happily calling my `populateData` in some other thread while a system invoked layout phase messed things up, in between :(

Comment: Like I said, that won't fix your race condition. The way to fix that is to subclass UITableView and override layoutSubviews. Surround [super layoutSubviews] with a lock such that layoutSubviews and populateData cannot run at the same time. Various types of locks should work, but @synchronized is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 6):

You should split your `populateData` function. Lets say for example into `fetchDatabaseRows` and `populateDataWithRows`. The `fetchDatabaseRows` should retrieve the rows into memory in its own thread and a new data structure. When the IO part is done, then you should call `populateDataWithRows` (and then `reloadData`) in the UI thread. `populateDataWithRows` should modify the collections used by the TableView.

Comment: You are not getting my point. I know your scheme should work in most of the cases and I have implemented similar constructs as suggested by @Paulw11. But what I actually wanted to know is when the `reloadData` actually completes binding everything. Or even worse, how I might determine that any rendering phase of `UITableView`had actually been completed since in iOS11 (and may be in iOS10 as well) I found that rendering is also performed implicitly without any developer invocation.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but: `reloadData` is finished when the function call returns, but only if you are on the same thread. The trouble is the various calls to `cellForRowAtIndex`. You will need your current `populateData` and `reloadData` calls to be atomic. As you have already noticed, that is annoyingly hard if those two need to execute on separate threads. That is why the smart people came up with constructions like actors and message queues. My advice stands and boils down to: do not modify data, used in thread 1 (example: UI), in any other thread... delegate it to the correct thread.

Comment: I totally agree with you that a smart coder could overcome the situation with a similar trick like you have said and I don't have any issue with it. The only dilemma is I want to understand the knowhow to overcome the hurdle of the simplest path without making it through the other ways.

Answer (score 1):

UIKit runs on main thread. All UI updates must be on main thread only. There is no race condition if updates to data source happens on main thread only.

Important to understand is that you need to protect data. So if you are using semaphore or mutex or anything like this construct is always:

1. claim the resource for me. (ex: mutex.lock())
2. do the processing
3. unlock the resource (ex: mutex.unlock())

Thing is, that because UI thread is for UI and background thread is used for processing you can not lock shared data source, because you would lock UI thread as well. Main thread would wait for unlock from background thread. So this construct is big NO-NO. That means your populateData() function must create copy of data in the background while UI is using its own copy on main thread. When data are ready, just move the update into main thread (no need for semaphore or mutex)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update datasource for table view here
            //call reload data
        });
```

Another thing:
viewWillAppear is not the place to do this update. Because you have navigation where you push your detail, you may do the swipe to dismiss, and in the midle just change your mind and stay in detail. However, vc1 viewWillAppear will be called. Apple should rename that method to "viewWillAppearMaybe" :). So right thing to do is to create a protocol, define method that will be called and use delegation to call the update function just once. This will not cause crash bug, but why to call update more than once? Also, why you are fetching all items, if only one has changed? I would update just 1 item.

One more:
You are probably creating reference cycle. Be careful when using self in blocks.

Your first example would be almost good if it looked like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  dispatch_async(self.application.commonWorkerQueue, ^{
    NSArray* newData = [self populateData]; //this creates new array, don't touch tableView data source here!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableItems = newData; //replace old array with new array
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //reload
    });
  });
}
```

(self.tableItems is NSArray, simple data source for tableView as an example of data source)

Comment: First, my construct using semaphore is for blocking the background thread and signaling the semaphore from the main thread. So I'm not sure what might hold me back? Second I'm not sure why `self` inside a block might be treated as harmful until I'm holding a strong reference of the block in `self` causing a retain cycle.

Comment: Thirdly right you are! I'm already doing it the way something like you have mentioned in your last block of code. And I understand that delegation is a good way to achieve my goal. But please understand the goal of my question. This is not regarding how I can achieve this rather regarding what's wrong UIKit? Think of a situation where two simultaneous `viewWillAppear:` calls that get invoked along with a system invoked layout call that also calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` in turn. Do you feel that all the populate/reload calls would still be serialized like it used to be earlier?

Comment: To the 1. comment: You have no control over UITableView code, so you can not put any sync code in it ;). You are just providing delegate for data source. This is why nothing will hold you back and you will have race conditions if you modify your data in background thread. About self in blocks: I just said be careful, it is not harmful if you know what you are doing.

Comment: to the 2. comment: There is nothing wrong with UIKit, UIKit is main thread only, you only get it to other thread if you do it. And in most cases it will be a bug. In Xcode9 there is nice tool to catch it. It is called Thread sanitizer. You can find it under Edit scheme ->Diagnostic. I am not sure why you think there are two simultaneous viewWillAppear calls?

Comment: Exactly. I don't have any control over complete UIKit rendering, now but that is what I loved about UIKit so much until now. It used to call back my code every time it needed something and was never smart enough to render anything out of the box if I didn't ask for that. Regarding the reference cycle I'm not sure what made you think that my code, that I posted, could create one! It'd be really helpful if you could pointed me out any potential occurrence.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I beg to disagree. There's obviously something wrong with UIKit in the latest versions since it doesn't behave anymore in the way the developers might expect. When I'm are calling `reloadData` all that I would expect that tableview would immediately reload its visible rows but tableview started to treat it as `registerReloadRequest` which is not a UIKit API but certainly that'd be a more intuitive name now on.

Comment: And by writing simultaneous `viewWillAppear:` calls I meant to say interleaved invocation of the blocks residing inside `viewWillAppear:`. Think of situation where user brings up VC1 calling `viewWillAppear:`, quickly jumps to VC2 and comes back again calling `viewWillAppear:` before the previous call completes. Moreover a layout call will be invoked before each appearance of VC1 calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in turn. I was trying to describe a similar situation only.

Comment: Frankly I must admit your reply is the most convincing one I found here as an answer though a similar construct was already proposed by @Paulw11 in the comments section of the question before starting the bounty. Unfortunately I cant upvote more than once and cant accept it as an answer since it doesn't address my concern regarding controlling the UIKit behavior to keep in sync with my code and not vice versa. By now I guess is this is not achievable at all :(

Comment: Well, there is apparently no problem with viewWillAppear. It also should be renamed to viewWillAppearMaybe :) But that is not a problem with UIKit. It is a legacy name that has changed behavior over time and developers can not change the name because of backward compatibility. Anyway, there is no problem with capturing self in blocks as shown in your code fragment. There is no memleak. Problem is more subtle. There is no way you cancel ongoing block if you start invoking viewWillAppear() function (interactive dismiss a cancel it). That's real problem.

Comment: I am a bit lost what you really want to achieve. You got code fragment that will do what you need, important part is to have a copy of data and change data source and reloadData on main thread. You still need to fix 'stupid user' behavior if displaying VC2 and dismissal is happening faster than populateData() execution time. There is no need to control UIKit more. You should post what you do in populateData. That could explain why you need to control UIKit more ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Update: after looking at your question a bit more thoroughly, it seems like the root cause of your problem is using a mutable backing data structure for your tableview. The system expects that the data will never change without an explicit call to `reloadData` in the same run loop iteration as the data change. The rows have always been loaded lazily.

As other folks have said, the solution is to use a `readwrite` property with an immutable value. When the data processing completes, update the property and call `reloadData`, both on the main queue.

Comment: `dispatch_sync` is nothing but a `dispatch_async` and a `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and that is what I'm doing using a semaphore only inside a further dispatch block on the main queue expecting the layout pass gets completed in the mean time. Also setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount ` property of a `NSOperationQueue` to 1 effectively makes it a serial queue what my `commonWorkerQueue` already is. Could you please elaborate your idea a bit more for my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that because you have referee cycle when accessing self.tableView inside getMain. Ans there is leaked versions of this table view somewhere in background which started to crash app in iOS 11

There is a chance that you can verify this with memory graph in Xcode.

To fix this access you need access weak copy of self like this

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_async(self.application.commonWorkerQueue, ^{
            if (!weakSelf) { return; }
            [weakSelf populateData]; //populate datasource
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf.tableView reloadData]; //reload table view
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: This code have race condition in populateData. You can not update data source that is used on main thread by tableview from background thread. you need a copy. But good point about using self in blocks ;)

Comment: I think your idea is somewhat wrong. `self` is never harmful in a block until it holds a strong reference of the block itself, causing a retain cycle. And my code is already profiled for potential memory leak without any occurrence :)

Comment: You can read "Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self" section https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html in apple docs. they advice not to capture self inside blocks

Comment: You might easily find that the block has been set as a strong (copied) property of the class that has been described in the example. So `self` holds a strong reference of the block causing a retain cycle and that situation has already been mentioned in my previous comment. Otherwise like I said, it is perfectly ok to capture `self` inside a block and sometimes it is very much required.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS11, the proper way to do "the heavy-lifting of data loading task" is to implement the UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching protocol as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

If you properly implement 'tableView:prefetchRowsAtIndexPaths:', you don't have to worry about background threads, worker queues, temporary datasources, or thread synchronization. UIKit takes care of all of that for you.

Comment: I know about prefetching and had already played with it. However the idea of prefetching is somewhat different. It is meant for incrementally loading the datasource and it works best for incrementally fetching the actual resources described in the model (like some file or network resource whose URLs are given in the model). The model still need to be populated beforehand and that is what my `populateData` does. And I feel prefetching more than 1000 database rows all with individual database calls is gonna be an overkill for the app and this is only how prefetching should meant to work for me.

Comment: Hmmm. One would think that only the number of sections and number of rows in each section would need to be available in the datasource beforehand, but maybe that's not available to you. Without more information about populateData, it's tough to come up with a solution.

Also, FWIW, the change to reloadData came about in iOS5. Before that, calling reloadData would synchronously call cellForRowAtIndexPath before returning. AFAIK, that wasn't the case with iOS10.

Comment: Really! I had to change my code to keep in sync with UITableView rendering only since iOS10 as I found that `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` started being called in a completely new iteration of runloop and my code was running without a glitch till iOS9.*. So how on the earth I made it happen till that version if `reloadData` had been working out of sync starting from iOS5!

Comment: This one's pretty easy to test with some breakpoints & the iOS9 simulator and stepping over a reloadData call. What I see is that, in iOS9, reloadData calls the various dataSource methods necessary for determine the table's contentSize (numberOfSections:, numberOfRowsInSection:, heightForRowAtIndexPath:).  The cellForRowAtIndexPath: isn't called until the next time layoutSubviews is run